# how to filter Java HashMap in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to filter out map entries having values that are less than zero:

```
(filter #(< 0 (.getValue %)) map)
```

Where `map` is a Java map (instance of `HashMap`). I'm getting

```
actual: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod (Reflector.java:26)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that `map` is an instance of `HashMap`? Because this actually works:

```
=> (import [java.util HashMap])
java.util.HashMap
=> (def m (HashMap.))
#'.../m
=> (filter #(< 0 (.getValue %)) m)
()
=> (.put m 3 4)
nil
=> (.put m 5 -32)
nil
=> (filter #(< 0 (.getValue %)) m)
(#<Entry 3=4>)
```

So I suppose the error is somewhere else. Maybe if you show us the code creating your `map`? Oh, and BTW, you are filtering the values greater than zero instead of less than zero.

Another thing that might cause this error would be that the values inside your map are not really comparable with `<`, so you should check that too.